Operation of recvfrom() in Linux
I am trying to understand how recvfrom() works in linux.
I opened a raw socket and read ICMP packets on an interface.
What I thought was recvfrom() copies a packet from Kernel to the application.
I tried to read ICMP request packet and clear the buffer and expect I cannot receive ICMP reply.
But it seems I still receive ICMP reply.
Am I misunderstanding the network operation or there is something wrong in the code?
The default ICMP packet size was 98.
So, I have just used the packet length to check whether the packet read is ICMP or not.
What I want to do is receive an ICMP packet from an interface and clear or drop the packet buffer.
And that can actually break ICMP packet exchange or not.
I ran this program on the PC2 from the diagram below.
And send a ICMP packet from PC1 to PC3.
    +-------+       +-------+       +-------+                
    |       |       |       |       |       |
    | PC 1  | ----- | PC 2  | ----- | PC 3  |
    |       |       |       |       |       |  
    +-------+       +-------+       +-------+

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int32_t sock;
   int8_t buf[1522];
   int32_t ifindex;
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t bytes;
   struct sockaddr_ll sll;
   struct ifreq ifr;
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;

   time(&rawtime);
   info = localtime(&rawtime);

   sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   if (sock == -1)
   {
      printf("socket open failed\n");
      return 1;
   }

   strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth1", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
   ret = ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      printf("failed to get index\n");
      return -1;
   }

   sll.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
   sll.sll_ifindex   = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
   sll.sll_protocol  = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

   ret = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      close(sock);
      printf("interface binding error\n");
      return 1;
   }

   while(1)
   {
      bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, 1522, 0, NULL, NULL);
      if (bytes < 0)
      {
         printf("error in recvfrom\n");
         exit;
      }
      if (bytes == 98)
      {
         memset(buf, 0x0, 1522);
      }
      printf("%s : received bytes = %d\n", bytes);
   }

   close(sock);
   return 0;
}


How are PC1, PC2 and PC3 connected? Ethernet bridge or different IP networks? Are you trying to implement a firewall? If a packet is not destinated to your interface, you can't read it with recvfrom(). At least without promiscuous mode.

PC1<->PC2 and PC2<->PC3 are separated IP network. And PC2 has static route configured to deliver traffic between PC1 <->PC3. And as you can see from the source code, I didn't set promiscuous mode on the socket.

Since it's L3 routing, L2 address (MAC) in packets is address of PC2 interface, so you receive them. What is your question? What is expected behavior and what is observed?

Yes, that's correct. I thought PC2 is receiving the packet from PC1 and send it to PC3. How can I read the packet coming from PC1 to PC2 at the application on PC2 and drop it inside of the application. So, I want to make this ping failed with packet dropping added on PC2.

memset(buf, 0x0, 1522) - this makes no sense. You got a copy of packet and can't affect kernel's buffer this way. That's not how firewalls work. If you want to control packets from userspace, you can, for example, setup iptables NFQUEUE target, receive packets info (and contents, if needed) in your program with libnetfilter_queue and set verdict for them.
